# What is wrong with this for loop with a string?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

```
Start= 1
End= 10
change=0.5
for Start in range(Start,End,change) :
    print(Start)
```

What is wrong with this code? I was working at it in school and can't seem to use the for loop with a string.

Comment: Please tag the question with the appropriate programming language.

Comment: What language is this supposed to be? `python`? It looks like valid python, what problem are you having?

Comment: Umm it comes up with an error that says 'float cannot be interpreted as a interger'

Comment: There you go. You are trying to change an integer by a float-value. Try `Start = 1.0` instead of `Start = 1`.

Comment: I highly doubt that the error message actually has `interger` rather than `integer`. When posting a question here, you should really post the exact error message, by using your computer's copy-and-paste features.

Comment: @Vince: You have that backward: it's complaining that it has a float when it wants an integer.

Comment: Why does the title mention a `string`?  There is no mention of a string at all in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `range` wont support floating point `increment`,  Hence the error:

```
DeprecationWarning: integer argument expected, got float
```

So your  value at 0.5 needs to be an integer, and you can use mathematics to still get same output

```
Start= 2
End= 21
change=1
for Start in range(Start,End,change) :
    print(Start*0.5)
```